# Unlimited Disk Cache is not working in image loader 1.9.5

Tags: android, android-studio, universal-image-loader

Unlimited Disk Cache is not working in  universal-image-loader:1.9.5 
I wanna store image in sdcard.
Please share replacement of this code.
Here is my code:

```
public void initImageLoader() {

    try {
        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.app_name));
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).showImageOnFail(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).considerExifParams(true).build();

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        L.writeLogs(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Gradle Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see detail at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Configuration, the class name had changed to "UnlimitedDiskCache" but not "UnlimitedDiscCache" as you coded.